# Deleting a specific line of a file

Tags: python, regex, file, file-writing

Hi i'm trying to delete a line in my file but want to keep the rest of my lines.

```
f = open("myfile.html").read()
lines = f.readlines()
a = findall('<h2>\$.*', f)
f.close()
f = open("myfile.html","w")
for line in lines:
  if line!= a[0]:
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

When I use the code above, all my other lines in the file of my html is removed.

text trying to get rid of:

```
        <h2>Thank you</h2>
<h2>Please come again</h2> #Get rid of this line
```

Comment: Don't process HTML/XML with regexes...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, [no fear](https://gist.github.com/mgsisk/1094230)! =)

Comment: @grundic: my point exactly...

Comment: why? I'm using regex to find the line of tag I want to delete, then seeing if that tag is not equal to the line

Comment: @Kevin: [because...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @grundic you call that a regex? [This](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) is a regex.

Comment: @timgeb  ¿ⓧ_ⓧﮌ cool!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
with open("myfile.html", "w+") as f:
    content = f.read()
    f.write(re.sub(r'<\s*h2[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*h2>', '', content))
```

But as @Willem Van Onsem recommended, don't use regexes for XML/HTML, it's more robust to use XML parser, lxml of BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

When you write to same file, the content will be override. So,You need to open new file and write to that file as :

```
f = open("NEWFILE.html","w")
for line in lines:
  if line!= a[0]:
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```